# Import dmp file created in Oracle 11g (WE8ISO8859P1) to Oracle 11g XE database (AL32UTF8)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I am regularly given a dmp file that gets created using oracle v.11g (using the exp utility).

I used to import this file to the Western European edition of Oracle 10g XE.
The import would terminate successfully without warnings but there was an error log (alert_xe.log) that would contstantly increase in size because I was using the the 32 Bit Oracle Database on a 64 Bit Windows OS.

I have now installed 11g XE and I am trying to import the same dmp file but I am seeing the following in the import log file:

```
import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
export client uses WE8ISO8859P1 character set (possible charset conversion)
```

and the import terminates with warnings as I have a lot of the following errors:

```
IMP-00019: row rejected due to ORACLE error 12899
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 12899 encountered
ORA-12899: value too large for column XXX (actual: 256, maximum: 255)
```

I understand that the cause of the problem is that the source database is using byte semantics and my new 11g XE database is using multibyte character set.

I have no control over the source database so I cannot change anything there.

Moreover I cant pre-create the tables with columns definitions using character length semantics over byte semantics (as indicated here for example [Character set in Oracle 11g r2 XE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420177/character-set-in-oracle-11g-r2-xe)) as somethimes the source database schema gets changed (columns might get added) and I am not notified so that breaks the import.

Is there a solution to this problem?
Is there any way to use WE8MSWIN1252 with Oracle 11g XE?

Comment: I managed to change the character set following the steps from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779159/change-nls-character-set-parameters-on-oracle-11g-xe. Has anybody encountered issues when doing this? (I am importing to an empty database everytime so I didnt have an existing database to mess up)

Comment: Try setting NLS_LANG environment variable to match that of the source database.

Comment: @TenG, set NLS_LANG is useless, because the dump file included WE8ISO8859P1 encoding DDL and also set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS from BYTE to CHAR is useless.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't do it.

As it's stated in Oracle official documentation:

```
9 Oracle Database XE Character and Language Configurations

Oracle Database XE is available only in Universal character set and language configurations:

The database is created using Unicode(AL32UTF8) character set, which is suitable for global data in any language.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW138

The only workaround is to preallocate the tables in advanced.

Comment: I managed to change the character set as stated in the comment in the original question and the import worked ok. I know this is not officially supported but I dont need to do too many things with this Oracle database. I just drop all tables every time and import the new dmp file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
When I run this command

```
imp <username>/<password>@<hostname> file=<filename>.dmp log=<filename>.log
```

It was showing

```
import done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
export client uses AR8MSWIN1256 character set (possible charset conversion)
IMP-00031: Must specify FULL=Y or provide FROMUSER/TOUSER or TABLES arguments
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

That mean my oracle server is **AL32UTF8** character set and export dump file client use **AR8MSWIN1256** character set.

So I just changed the oracle character set to **AR8MSWIN1256** by using following command.

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET AQ_TM_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE AR8ISO8859P6;
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP;
```

Then run again

```
imp <username>/<password>@<hostname> file=<filename>.dmp log=<filename>.log  FULL=Y
```

I hope this anwser will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i was facing to transfer data from oracle 11g to oracle xe version. what steps i have used at that time shown below:
'CONN SYS/(YOUR sys user PASSWORD) AS SYSDBA

SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;

STARTUP restrict;

ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE WE8MSWIN1252;

SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;

STARTUP;'

Once oracle get started try to import your .dmp file after recreating user.